# How to merge two trees in golang ?

Tags: go, tree

The tree struct is below:

```
 type TreeData struct {
    Name          string      `json:"name"`
    Depth         int         `json:"depth"`
    Children      []TreeData  `json:"children"`
}
```

I have two trees, and I want merge them into one tree.
How can I do that?
If someone could show me your code, I would be very appreciate!!
I wonder if I could use the recursion way to finish the merge?

treeone:

```
{
     "name": ".",
     "depth": 1,
     "children": [
         {
             "name": "com",
             "depth": 2,
             "children": [
                 {
                     "name": "didi"
                     "depth": 3,
                     "children": [
                         {
                             "name": "dev",
                             "depth": 4,
                             "children": null
                         }
                     ]
                 }
             ]
         }
     ]
}
```

treetwo:

```
{
     "name": ".",
     "depth": 1,
     "children": [
         {
             "name": "com",
             "depth": 2,
             "children": [
                 {
                     "name": "didi"
                     "depth": 3,
                     "children": [
                         {
                             "name": "influxdb",
                             "depth": 4,
                             "children": [
                                 {
                                     "name": "cluster-one"
                                     "depth": 5
                                     "children": null
                                 }
                             ]    
                         } 
                     ]
                 }
             ]
         }
     ]
}
```

merge:

```
{
     "name": ".",
     "depth": 1,
     "children": [
         {
             "name": "com",
             "depth": 2,
             "children": [
                 {
                     "name": "didi"
                     "depth": 3,
                     "children": [
                         {
                             "name": "influxdb",
                             "depth": 4,
                             "children": [
                                 {
                                     "name": "cluster-one"
                                     "depth": 5
                                     "children": null
                                 }
                             ]
                         },
                         {
                            "name": "dev",
                            "depth": 4,
                            "children": null
                         }
                     ]
                 }
             ]
         }
     ]
}
```

Comment: Show us some code first.

Comment: I don't know how to do that......

Answer (score 0):

I find a good solution for golang to create a tree!!
http://blog.csdn.net/xtxy/article/details/50812392